# font size and margin differences between Safari and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I am noticing some differences when viewing my website in different browsers.

this is Safari :

[image]

And this is Chrome :

[image]

Why are there differences in font size and margins? 
I have tried pixels instead of em but didn't work

css code :

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.image {
    width : 100%;
}

#container {
    position :relative;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.signup, .signin {
cursor:pointer;
width :15%;
height:7%;
background: #EB6553;
border: 1px solid #979797;
border-radius: 5px;
/* Sign up : */
font-family: AmericanTypewriter;
font-size: 3em;
color: #000000;
}

.signup {
    position:absolute;
    top :58.5%;
    left: 30%
}

.signin {
    position:absolute;
    top : 58.5%;
    right: 30%;
}

.facebook {
position:absolute;
top: 86%;
left:40%;
cursor:pointer;
width: 22%;
height:5.5%;
background: #415E9B;
border: 1px solid #979797;
border-radius: 5px;
/* Sign in with faceboo: */
font-family: AmericanTypewriter;
font-size: 2em;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

html :

```
<div id='container'>
    <%= image_tag('Group.jpg', class: 'image') %> <br/>

    <div id='buttons'>
        <%= button_to "Sign up",  new_user_registration_path, :method => :get, class: 'signup'%><br/>
        <%= button_to "Sign in with facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), class: 'facebook' %><br/>
        <%= button_to "Log in",  new_user_session_path, class: 'signin', :method => :get %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting font-size in px rather than em.

Comment: I tried that, same problem.

Comment: Can you share the website or a fiddle link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had different zooming levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your css for crome and safari browser this way:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{



* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.image {
    width : 100%;
}

#container {
    position :relative;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.signup, .signin {
cursor:pointer;
width :15%;
height:7%;
background: #EB6553;
border: 1px solid #979797;
border-radius: 5px;
/* Sign up : */
font-family: AmericanTypewriter;
font-size: 3em;
color: #000000;
}

.signup {
    position:absolute;
    top :58.5%;
    left: 30%
}

.signin {
    position:absolute;
    top : 58.5%;
    right: 30%;
}

.facebook {
position:absolute;
top: 86%;
left:40%;
cursor:pointer;
width: 22%;
height:5.5%;
background: #415E9B;
border: 1px solid #979797;
border-radius: 5px;
/* Sign in with faceboo: */
font-family: AmericanTypewriter;
font-size: 2em;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

}
```